# How to group and show multiple directory names with Powershell Get-ChildItem

Tags: grouping, powershell-3.0

I would like to pass multiple directories, then get a count of how many files were created yesterday in each directory.

This is what I have cobbled together so far:

```
$DirNames = @('d:\Work\Test1','d:\Work\Test2')

Get-ChildItem $DirNames | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge (get-date).addDays(-1) }  | 
    Group {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | Sort Name -Desc | 
    Format-Table Name,Count -auto
```

Current Output:

```
Name       Count
----       -----
2014-03-25     4
```

It works fine for one directory, but I'm get confused how to show the the directory name in the output listing. The above count is for both directories, what I would like to see is:

Desired Output:

```
Directory      Date          Count
------------   ----------    -----
D:\Work\Test1  2014-03-25     2
D:\Work\Test2  2014-03-25     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ls $env:temp| group {$_.lastwritetime.tostring('yyyy-MM-dd')} | 
      ft name,count,@{
       'n' = 'Directory'; 
       'e' = { $_ |select -expa group | select -first 1 -expa psparentpath | Convert-Path }
      }
```

or you can use new pipelinevariable parameter with version 4

Comment: $DirName = @('d:\Work\Archive_EPIC_Incoming_Invoices_DO_NOT_DELETE','d:\Work\Archive_EPIC_DO_NOT_DELETE')

Get-ChildItem $DirName |  Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge (get-date).addDays(-1) }  | group {$_.Directory} | 
      Format-Table name,count,@{
       'n' = 'Directory'; 
       'e' = { $_ |select -expa group | select -first 1 -expa psparentpath | Convert-Path }
      }
Your version didn't handle two directories and no date selection; Above is my version of what you provided.  I'm getting the count and directory name, but now the date is not showing.

Comment: Also, I removed the abbreviations, because I verily understand what I'm doing with the full syntax.  Why is Date going in the "Name" column in yours, and the directory name is going in the "Name" column in my version?

Comment: What about this change to the group: group {$_.Directory,$_.CreationTime.ToShortDateString()}
Now it creates Name column which has both Directory and Date part of $_.CreationTime - almost what I need, but would be better to keep Date in separate column.